# export simple geometries to gltf?

Tags: python, gltf

I have a number of simple geometries (planes, e.g. [[0.002, 0.002], [0.002, 1.802], [1.042, 1.802], [1.042, 0.002], [0.002, 0.002]]) that I would like to output to glTF format. The JSON part of this seems straight forward, but how do I turn these simple geometries into binary data in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `pygltf`, which is a very well written library (built upon `numpy` and the standard `json` module) to import from or export to glTF files:

https://github.com/filonik/pygltf